# Trying to update a subset of a column in pandas and getting a warning

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new TimeZone column (according to the country code, such as 'UK').
I am doing it in a loop, going through each country code. (I realize there must be a way to do it with one line, without looping. But my actual usecase is much more complex).

I'm getting that dreaded warning in pandas - `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

I'm not sure what I should do in a different way.

```
fb.data['tz'] = ""
for country in fb.data['Country'].unique():
    TARGET_TZ = tzh.code_to_single_tz[country] if country != 'missing_value' else 'UTC'
    country_index = fb.data['Country'] == country
    fb.data['tz'][country_index] = TARGET_TZ
```

If you are interested in the full use case -  I'm also converting a UTC datetime to the "local" time in a new column (and therefore getting the warning twice, for `tz` and for `install_datetime_in_tz`:

```
tzh = TimezonesHelper()
fb.data['install_datetime_in_tz'] = ""
fb.data['tz'] = ""
fb.data['install_datetime_in_tz'] = fb.data['install_datetime_in_tz'].astype('datetime64')
for country in fb.data['Country'].unique():
    TARGET_TZ = tzh.code_to_single_tz[country] if country != 'missing_value' else 'UTC'
    country_index = fb.data['Country'] == country
    fb.data['install_datetime_in_tz'][country_index] = fb.data['install_date'][country_index].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert(TARGET_TZ).dt.tz_localize(None)
    fb.data['tz'][country_index] = TARGET_TZ
```

Comment: One idea is change order in last 2 rows of code with `loc` `fb.data.loc[country_index, 'install_datetime_in_tz'] = fb.data.loc[country_index, 'install_date'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert(TARGET_TZ).dt.tz_localize(None)
fb.data.loc[country_index, 'tz'] = TARGET_TZ`, [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters)

Comment: That did the trick @jezrael. Thank you!